# How to set params dynamically for AjaxUpload?

Tags: jquery, file-upload

I have created a function to upload a file using [this library](https://github.com/valums/ajax-upload) as follows:

```
new AjaxUpload($('#addImage'), {
                action: 'SaveDataBank.aspx',
                name: 'uploadimage',
                dataType: 'json',
                params: { clientid: GetSelectedClient() }
                onSubmit: function (file, ext) {
                },
                onComplete: function (file, response) {
                }
            });
```

I would like to perform some task before opening a file dialog. How could I update the above code?

**UPDATE:**

I would like to pass a parameter dynamically with the file upload. I have a dropdown containing a list of client ids. If I click on the Upload button it will open File Dialog. I would then like it to pass in the selected client from the dropdown. Currently, it only passes the initially selected value.

```
params: { clientid: GetSelectedClient() },
```

The above line does not work as per my requirement.

Comment: Maybe you should call the function you want to do BEFORE calling ajax?  Or if the function you want BEFORE is success then call AJAX..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### First idea (which doesn't work)

Try binding a click handler to the button. If you don't return false or stop propagation, it will trigger the file uploader after the click handler finishes:

```
$('#addImage').click(function(){
    // code here
});

new AjaxUpload($('#addImage'), {
                action: 'SaveDataBank.aspx',
                name: 'uploadimage',
                dataType: 'json'
            });
```

This doesn't work because the AjaxUpload library creates an input element which it puts over the top of the button when you hover over the button. It's actually the input element that you click.

#### Work around

Bind to the click event of the input that you *actually* click on. This does not exist on page load, so we have to use the jQuery [live function](http://api.jquery.com/live/):

```
new AjaxUpload($('#addImage'), {
                action: 'SaveDataBank.aspx',
                name: 'uploadimage',
                dataType: 'json'
            });

$('input[type="file"]').live('click', function(e){
    // code here
});
```

See [my updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Spycho/KHns9/1/) for a working example.

#### Passing dynamic data

To pass dynamic data along with your file upload, add a `setData` call in the `onSubmit` handler:

```
new AjaxUpload($('#addImage'), {
            action: 'SaveDataBank.aspx',
            name: 'uploadimage',
            dataType: 'json',
            onSubmit: function (file, ext) {
                this.setData({clientid: GetSelectedClient()});
            }
        });
```

#### Conclusions

This shows that the library is a bit awkward to work with. You don't click the button, so you won't get normal button effects (i.e. it becoming indented when mouse down). Any JavaScript which relies on the button events will not work as expected. You can go with the above solution, but personally, I would look for a different library. Maybe [the newer one that replaces this](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/)? [Here are a bunch of others](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/ajax-upload) and [some more](http://www.webdeveloperjuice.com/2010/02/13/7-trusted-ajax-file-upload-plugins-using-jquery/).

Comment: I have updated my answer with details of how to add dynamic data to the file upload.

Comment: I have added setData but it is giving me an **Error: setData is not defined**

Comment: ah, it's an instance function, so it should be `this.setData`. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Excellent answer! finally it is working.. Thanks you very much for long support till getting solution. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

### first,you can set a global object:

```
AjaxUploadObj=new AjaxUpload($('#addImage'), {
               action: 'SaveDataBank.aspx',
               name: 'uploadimage',
               dataType: 'json',
               params: { clientid: GetSelectedClient() }
               onSubmit: function (file, ext) {
               },
               onComplete: function (file, response) {
               }
           });
```

### then,you can change property's value through AjaxUploadObj._settings

for example:
AjaxUploadObj._setting.action="http://mustrank.com/dosomething.php"

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$('#addImage').mousedown(function(){
    //code here
});
```

Or

```
$('#addImage').bind('mousedown',function(){
    //code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://github.com/valums/file-uploader#instance-methods), following should work for you:

```
onSubmit : function(id, fileName){
    var delete=$("#check-delete-previous").is(":checked");
    this.setParams({ "deletePrevious" : delete });
},
```

Make sure you are using latest version, because older versions may not set callback functions correctly.

Edit:
In fact, following worked only for me:

```
onSubmit : function(id, fileName){
    var delete=$("#check-delete-previous").is(":checked");
    this.params.deletePrevious = delete;
},
```